# Sagemaker ProcessingInput/Output unable to access data from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am building a Sagemaker pipeline and the first processor's job is to take some data already stored in s3, do some processing on it, and push it back to s3 again. This is how the Processor and ProcessorStep look like :

```
        parse_json_processor = Processor(
        role=config["AWS"]["AWS_ROLE"],
        image_uri=DATA_PROCESSING_IMAGE_URI,
        instance_count=1,
        instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
        volume_size_in_gb=5,
        max_runtime_in_seconds=18000,
        base_job_name=f"data-processing-{market}",
        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    )

    parse_json_step = ProcessingStep(
        name=f"data_processing_{market}",
        processor=parse_json_processor,
        cache_config=cache_config,
        job_arguments=["--market", market],
        inputs=[
            ProcessingInput(
                source="s3_input_path_before_procssing",
                input_name="input",
                destination="/opt/ml/processing/data/common/joined-data",
            ),
        ],
        outputs=[
            ProcessingOutput(
                source="/opt/ml/processing/data/common/joined-data-processed",
                output_name="joined_data_processed",
                destination=f"s3_output_path_after_processing",
            )
        ],
    )
```

The AWS role that I use has the required access:
[image: AWS Role]

I am unable to figure out the reason why this process is not reading and writing data from s3. I was able to manually debug by having the copy data command in the Dockerfile of the container and then the Python script in the container is able to read the data from the container and do the processing and the pipeline step runs successfully but the processed data is still not pushed to s3.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the SageMaker Pipeline has the correct permissions? The default execution role for the SageMaker domain may be used instead. Perhaps pass a role directly to `parse_json_step` as if may not assume the permissions from `parse_json_processor`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
What do you mean by "pass a role directly to parse_json_step as if may not assume the permissions from parse_json_processor"? The role could only be passed to the Processor and not the ProcessingStep. Then how do I pass the role directly to the step? @fucalost